# Pound sign (£) missing from font in PDF using tcpdf & PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, tcpdf

I have used the `addTTFfont()` method within the latest version of tcpdf (5.9.134) to convert the Arial font. However it does not print the British pound sign (£) and appears as though it skipped converting this character.  All it prints is a blank box where the character should be.

Does anyone know if it's possible to list custom characters for the font conversion to include?

Thanks

**WORKAROUND:**

When I used this site to convert my fonts, the £ signs appeared correctly:

http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

I can only imagine then that I am not converting the fonts properly using the `addTTFfont` method.  Anyway, for now I'm happy as the £ signs are appearing.

Comment: Does the blank box has a border?

Comment: You're using the wrong character to make that font display the `£` sign. What is the right character code for that font for the `£` sign?

Comment: @hakre I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but when I use windows character map it shows U+00A3 or 0163 for that symbol. Is that the character code you are talking about?

Comment: `U+00A3` is the unicode-codepoint which represents that character, yes. So how do you tell TCPDF which character(s) it should use? Is there some specification how you need to encode them for example? Charset encoding always plays a role if you pass a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WORKAROUND:**

When I used this site to convert my fonts, the £ signs appeared correctly:

http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

I can only imagine then that I am not converting the fonts properly using the addTTFfont method. Anyway, for now I'm happy as the £ signs are appearing.

Comment: Had some render issues with fonts, and converting with this site did the trick for me. So still a usable option.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help you but I recall we had a similar problem with pdfLib and the problem was that it would not render "£" sign if it was in `UTF-8`. We had to store pound sign `ASCII` value to send to pdfLib.

Possibly totally unrelated but I thought it may give you something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about 8 years too late to the party, but for anyone who comes across this via Google, I had the same problem - TCPDF was rendering a question mark instead of a literal pound sign

```
$this->MultiCell($width, $height, "£120", $border, 'L', 0, $newline, $x, $y, true, 0, false, false, $height, $valign, false);
```

The default encoding for TCPDF is UTF-8, and it turned out that I was saving my PHP file in Notepad++ in ANSI encoding. All I had to do go to the Encoding menu in Notepad++ and change it to UTF-8, and re-save the file.

That's it. Hope that helps someone.